# Error con condicional en pascal

Tags: pascal

el error que tengo en mi programa es el siguiente, quiero crear un programa en el cual el usuario digite numeros del 1 al 7 pero tambien necesito establecer una condicion, la cual es que si el usuario digita un numero menor a 1  y mayor a 7 el programa no se ejecuta. Esta condicion es la que me esta dando problemas ya que no se esta cumpliendo con ninguna de las posibilidades.

```
program dias;
 USES CRT;
 var num:integer;
 begin

 writeln('Digite un numero del 1 al 7');
 num:=2;

 if ((num>=7) and (num<=1) ) then
 begin
 writeln('LUNES');
 end

 else
 begin
writeln('ERROR');
end;


readkey;

 end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se debe a que es necesario que inviertas tu condición, esto lucirá de la siguiente manera.

```
    program dias;
    USES CRT;
    var num:integer;
    begin

    writeln('Digite un numero del 1 al 7');
    num:=2;

    if ((num>=1) and (num>=7)) then
    begin
       writeln('LUNES');
    end

    else
    begin
       writeln('ERROR');
    end;


    readkey;

    end.
```

Espero responder a tu inquietud.